# CORS request from a file:/// url for a http://... url?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, safari, cors

On OS X I have a simple html page which I open using a `file:///...` url. This page contains javascript which attempts to load a `http://...` resource.

This works using Safari, but it doesn't work under Firefox or Chrome.
The error message I get from those browsers are:

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://whatever/etc. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

Is there to get the page to work under Firefox and Chrome?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable same origin policy in Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome)